# Error from autopostback: “Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found.”

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I am trying to call autopostback statements, the following error occurs:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Member not found.

Error statement is: `theForm.submit();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
        if (!theForm) {
            theForm = document.form1;
        }
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
            if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                theForm.submit();//error statement
            }
        }

    </script>
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Does that aspx page have a `<form runat=server>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like  you have somewhere wrong or contradictory 'id'. You should check your html form all elements ID.`May be you have given ID like "Submit"`. You cannot use "submit" as id in HTML.It will generate error like yours.

> For more reference visit this link

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t110670-__dopostback-fails-on-web-form-submit-net-2-0-a.html